# How to exclude paths in Pug?

Tags: html, pug

I'm trying exclude paths in Pug, that should not be among compiled files in  dist folder, but nothig help!.

I renamed dir **parts** to **_parts**, **parts/footer.pug** to **_parts/_footer.pug**, but I still see compiled files in **dist/_parts/** dir.

So, how can exclude some paths in Pug. (I use **pug-cli** as compiler)?

Comment: Why are you trying to fight the default behavior?  You're swimming against the current here and will struggle to find a solution to this, not to mention future problems that this will create if you do find a workaround.

Comment: This thread may be helpful: https://github.com/pugjs/pug-cli/issues/40#issuecomment-421718298

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible with bash
And if you're on Windows, you can use git bash
You just need to prefix the ignored file with "_"

So, suppose your project directory looks like this:-

- my-project/

  - index.html
  - pugjs

    - _head.pug
    - index.pug

you can do:-

```bash
pug -w "$(ls ./pugjs/!(_*))" -o ./
```

Now what does this line do?
basically, the "$(ls ./pugjs/!(**))" lists all files that don't have the prefix "*"
they get passed as files paths argument to pug